# Match word (starting with plus symbol) in pandas data frames

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas data frames. I would like to find matching strings in one specific column ("keyword") exist in both data frames.

```
keyword                     adGroup     goal6Value   adCost
[aaaa]                      (not set)   0            0.0
+bb +bb                     (not set)   0            0.0
+cc +cc                     (not set)   2072         0.0
[dddd]                      (not set)   0            0.0
```

The second data frame:

```
keyword                     status      Max          Min
[aaaa]                      (not set)   0.1          0.0
+bb +bb                     (not set)   0.2          0.0
+ff +ff                     (not set)   0.1          0.0
[gggg]                      (not set)   0.3          0.0
```

I would like the output to return all columns if the keyword is available in both data frames (keyword column). The output should look like this:

```
keyword    status       Max     Min    adGroup    goal6Value   adCost
[aaaa]    (not set)     0.1     0.0   (not set)   0            0.0
+bb +bb   (not set)     0.2     0.0   (not set)   0            0.0
```

I have changed the data type for keyword column into string for both data frames. 
I have tried these options:

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, on='keyword')
```

and

```
df1.set_index('keyword').join(df2.set_index('keyword'))
```

However, both options only matched the keyword with brackets and did not return the keywords starting with a plus symbol even when they are available in both data frames.

Is there a way to match the keyword with the plus symbol as well in pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot recreate your issue, the below test works fine. I'd suggest casting your keyword column as dtype object in both dataframes (`df1['keyword'] = df1['keyword'].astype(object)` | `df2['keyword'] = df2['keyword'].astype(object)`)

dtype object seems to work for me, as shown below:

```
data_1 = {'keyword': ['[aaaa]','+bb +bb','+cc +cc','[dddd]'],
          'adGroup': ['(not set)','(not set)','(not set)','(not set)'],
          'goal6Value': ['0','0','2072','0'],
          'adCost': ['0.0','0.0','0.0','0.0']}

data_2 = {'keyword': ['[aaaa]','+bb +bb','+ff +ff','[gggg]'],
          'status': ['(not set)','(not set)','(not set)','(not set)'],
          'Max': ['0.1','0.2','0.1','0.3'],
          'Min': ['0.0','0.0','0.0','0.0']}

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data_1)
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data_2)

test = pd.merge(df_1, df_2, on='keyword')
test.head()

keyword adGroup goal6Value  adCost  status  Max Min
0   [aaaa]  (not set)   0   0.0 (not set)   0.1 0.0
1   +bb +bb (not set)   0   0.0 (not set)   0.2 0.0

test.dtypes

keyword       object
adGroup       object
goal6Value    object
adCost        object
status        object
Max           object
Min           object
dtype: object
```

Alternatively, perhaps there are some leading/lagging spaces on your keyword column that may not exist across dataframes. This can be remedied with Pandas.series.str.strip(). [Pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html).

Comment: Thanks! The leading/lagging spaces are the issues. I've removed leading/lagging spaces in the data frames `df1['keyword'] = df1['keyword'].str.strip()` and `pd.merge()` matched the keywords with plus symbols.

Answer (score 0):

I could not recreate the issue as I could merge the two dfs beblow

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'keyword':['[aaaa]','+bbbb'],'adGroup':['something','something']})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'keyword':['[aaaa]','+bbbb'],'adGroup':['something2','something2']})
df1.merge(df2,on='keyword')

    adGroup_x   keyword adGroup_y
0   something   [aaaa]  something2
1   something   +bbbb   something2
```

May be you need to change the type.

Comment: I have tried this solution and does not give the output I want. I have changed the data type too.

Comment: @mahf_i you copy all the code above and not working?

Comment: @JamesLiu I have updated the question to better reflect my issue. The keyword can have multiple plus symbols.

Comment: @mahf_i No of `+` does not matter if they are of the same type. merge is similar to sql join statement and works pretty much in the same fashion.

Answer (score -1):

**EDITED**

pd.merge work fine, I can't reproduce the problem, too

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, on='keyword')
```